# Telerik Kendo Grid Filter Issue

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, grid, telerik

Here am using telerik kendo grid, It has filters,
    those filter initially is not shown when a refresh a page its shows.
    May i know what was the problem, please let me know. Thanks.

[image: Telerik Kendo Grid Filter Issue]

Comment: What did you expect? It looks exactly as on the demo pages: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX with WebBlue skin:
[Grid - Basic Filtering](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/filtering/basic-filtering/defaultcs.aspx?skin=WebBlue)

You can ensure that you are not using the DataBind() method to bind the grid:
[How to bind RadGrid properly on server-side](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/grid/details/how-to-bind-radgrid-properly-on-server-side)

And if you want to apply initial filtering, you can check the suggestions provided in the following post:
[Telerik forums for RadGrid - 
RadGrid enable filter code behind](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-enable-filter-code-behind#cel1slcp-U-pmV28CfXTrg)

I hope this will prove helpful.